# Crear una vista compleja con 3 tablas

Tags: sql, oracle

Este son los comandos SQL para generar 3 tablas, necesito hacer una vista compleja que contenga las 3 tablas, pero no se como hacer digamos para que me relacione los datos de la tabla 1 con la tabla 2 y luego la tabla 2 con la tabla 3, puedo hacer vistas de 2 tablas pero no tengo idea de como hacer las de 3 tablas

```
        CREATE TABLE medicamento
          (
             id_medicamento    NUMBER(5) NOT NULL,
             id_enfermedad     NUMBER(5) NOT NULL,
             nombre            VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
             descripcion       VARCHAR2(50),
             fecha_vencimiento DATE,
             CONSTRAINT id_medicamento_pk PRIMARY KEY(id_medicamento)
          ); 

        CREATE TABLE enfermedad
          (
             id_enfermedad     NUMBER(5) NOT NULL,
             nombre_enfermedad VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
             descripcion       VARCHAR2(50),
             complejidad       VARCHAR2(30),
             CONSTRAINT id_enfermedad_pk PRIMARY KEY(id_enfermedad)
          );

 CREATE TABLE tratamiento
          (
             id_tratamiento NUMBER(5) NOT NULL,
             id_enfermedad  NUMBER(5) NOT NULL,
             id_medicamento NUMBER(5) NOT NULL,
             descripcion    VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
             observaciones  VARCHAR2(50),
             CONSTRAINT id_tratamiento_pk PRIMARY KEY(id_tratamiento),
             CONSTRAINT id_tratamientoENF_fk FOREIGN KEY(id_enfermedad) REFERENCES
             enfermedad(id_enfermedad),
             CONSTRAINT id_medicamentoMEDI_fk FOREIGN KEY(id_medicamento) REFERENCES
             medicamento(id_medicamento)
          );
```

Comment: no termino de entender tu problema.. es solo agregar otro join a tu consulta...

Comment: encontre este ejemplo, pero seria algo asi?

Comment: JOIN hallazgos ON hallazgos.id_usuarios = usuarios.id_usuarios 

JOIN lovi ON lovi.id_usuarios = usuarios.id_usuarios

Comment: exacto.. probalo y cuando tengas un problema con eso, mostranos que paso y ahi podremos ayudarte

Comment: Logre hacer esta vista, ya me diras tu si esta bien o no : create or replace force view prueba as
select e.NOMBRE_ENFERMEDAD, m.NOMBRE, t.ID_TRATAMIENTO
FROM ENFERMEDAD e
JOIN TRATAMIENTO t on e.ID_ENFERMEDAD = t.ID_ENFERMEDAD
JOIN MEDICAMENTO m on t.ID_MEDICAMENTO = m.ID_MEDICAMENTO

Comment: despues de mejorarla un poco, esto fue lo que obtuve, los resultados no se duplican y las 3 tablas los datos se relacionan de forma correcta : create or replace force view ENFER_TRATA_MEDIC as
select e.NOMBRE_ENFERMEDAD as ENFERMEDAD, m.NOMBRE AS MEDICAMENTO ,e.DESCRIPCION AS DIAGNOSTICO, t.DESCRIPCION AS TRATAMIENTO, t.observaciones
FROM ENFERMEDAD e
JOIN TRATAMIENTO t on e.ID_ENFERMEDAD = t.ID_ENFERMEDAD
JOIN MEDICAMENTO m on t.ID_MEDICAMENTO = m.ID_MEDICAMENTO

Answer (score 0):

Juanito,

Esta es una vista que se centra en los medicamentos y muestra aquellas enfermedades y tratamientos que tiene asociados.

Usamos LEFT JOIN porque de esa manera tambien apareceran en la vista los medicamentos que no tengan una enfermedad y/o tratamiento relacionados.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW v_medicamentos AS
    SELECT m.*, e.*, t.*
    FROM             medicamento m
           LEFT JOIN enfermedad e  ON e.id_enfermedad = m.id_enfermedad
           LEFT JOIN tratamiento t ON t.id_enfermedad = m.id_enfermedad 
                                  AND t.id_medicamento = m.id_medicamento
    ORDER BY m.id_medicamento, m.id_enfermedad, t.id_tratamiento 
/
```

En esta vista se ven todos los medicamentos y su relacion con las enfermedades que trata